# Join Table to get name of column with two id's

Tags: mysql

I have a bad designed database and need to join two tables correctly.
I need a query with all fields from Table1 and replace books_ordered
with the first title in table2 with the same id.
The first title of each book id is in german and i need only the german title.

EDIT: I updated the tables to be more specific

This is an example table.

Table1

```
|___id___|__name__|_books_ordered_|
|    1   | peter  |     24,25,26  |
|    2   | olaf   |     25,26     |
|    3   | walter |     24        |
|    4   | tim    |     24,25     |
```

Table2

```
|___id___|____title____|___book_id___|
|    1   | Das Haus    |     24      |
|    4   | The house   |     24      |
|    7   | la maison   |     24      |
|    10  | la casa     |     24      |
|    2   | Der Baum    |     25      |
|    5   | The tree    |     25      |
|    8   | L'arbre     |     25      |
|    11  | El árbol    |     25      |
|    3   | Das Boot    |     26      |
|    6   | The boat    |     26      |
|    9   | Le bateau   |     26      |
|    12  | El barco    |     26      |
```

What i have so far is this query:

```
SELECT t.name, tr.title, FROM Table1 AS t 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS tr 
ON t.books_ordered = tr.book_id 
WHERE tr.id<3
```

But the result is just giving me the title of the first id in books_ordered back. Kinda like this:

```
|___name____|___title_____|
|   Peter   |   Das Haus  |
|   Peter   |   Das Haus  |
|   Peter   |   Das Haus  |
|   Olaf    |   Der Baum  |
|   Olaf    |   Der Baum  |
|   Walter  |   Das Haus  |
|   Tim     |   Das Haus  |
|   Tim     |   Das Haus  |
```

The result what i need should look like this:

```
|___name____|___title__________________________|
|   Peter   |   Das Haus, Der Baum, Das Boot   |
|   Olaf    |   Der Baum, Das Boot             |
|   Walter  |   Das Haus                       |
|   Tim     |   Das Haus, Der Baum             |
```

Comment: update your question and add your expected result  please

Comment: and is not cleat how you get seprated rows  using the book_ordered comma separated values ..

Comment: I updated to be more clear about my issue

Comment: looking to you updated question  .. i think you can't do this using sql only  ..but you need  to process the book_ordered server side for obtain the related title

Comment: The marked duplicate question solved my problem, thank you anyways

Comment: this for me is not a duplicated  question  ..

Comment: i have reopened  (think)

Answer (score 0):

***Try this***

```
SELECT t.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tr.title SEPARATOR ', '), FROM Table1 AS t 
INNER JOIN Table2 AS tr 
ON t.books_ordered = tr.book_id 
WHERE tr.id<3
GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: This throws an error that the syntax is wrong but i solved it already. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the linked duplicate question.
The answer for this specific problem is:

```
SELECT distinct t.name, tr.title 
    FROM Table1 AS t 
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS tr 
    ON find_in_set(tr.book_id, t.books_ordered)
```